# Qt: the promoted widget is not recognized as a member of 'Ui:MainWindow'

Tags: qt

In the `mainwindow.ui`, I have dragged a widget to the maindow. Then I promote the widget to a class `RenderImage` predefined in a source header file, `renderImage.h` (`class RenderImage : public QWidget`;it is used for live display of acquired images), as shown in the figure below.
[image]

In the `mainwindow.cpp`, there is a line code involving using `renderImage`:

```
if((camera && process) == NULL)
{
    camera = new CMUCamera();
    process = new ImageProcessing();
    ui->renderImage->setProcess(process);
    qDebug()<<"camera = "<<camera;
}
```

Building the program gives an error: `C2039: 'renderImage': is not a member of 'Ui::MainWindow'`.

I though the promoted RenderImage in the framework of MainWindow would be automatically recognized as a member of MainWindow. Are there any steps I missed for this?

Comment: the widget of type `RenderImage` is called `widget`, it is not called `renderImage`, it changes `ui->renderImage->setProcess(process);` to `ui->widget->setProcess(process);` or edit the name in the view you show.

Comment: If you check the name of the widget is on the left and the name of the class on the right.

Comment: @eyllanesc: Thanks, I will try that change!

Comment: @eyllanesc: I have renamed the objectName of the added widget as 'renderImage', but it still cannot resolve the issue: 'renderImage': is not a member of 'Ui:MainWinwo'.

Comment: share me your code zipped through drive, dropbox, etc, to check what is the problem, maybe the error is elsewhere.

Comment: shows the updated screenshot of the design.

Comment: @the project requires two external support libraries: CMU1394 and Opencv3.2, but it is to implement a straightforward task of image acquisition.

Comment: I'm just going to check what the problem is, I'll see how to skip the dependencies

Comment: @eyllanesc ok, I will share it with you right now.

Comment: @eyllanesc: please the files at https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g61H4XWKYRG6wbguxJ8JEiqwPhYYQ5ZO/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I have changed the name in the design, I have saved it and it works correctly. I think you made the change but you have not saved the change.

Comment: I think you are right. I will see how it works tomorrow. Thanks